# How to split string in equal size part and copy it to temporary string array for further processing in c language?

Tags: c

Enter String="HELLOGOODMORNING"
splitsize=8
I want to split it in 8-8 size and store it in tempstring[8] and to independently processing on it,and then the same on the another 8 char ,these till string does not end.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void passtofun(char string[8])
{
//logic of operation
}
void main()
{
 char caETF[8];
 char caText="HELLOGOODMORNING";//strlen will in multiple of 8.
 int i,j,len;
 len=strlen(caText);
for(i = 0; i < len; i+=8)
  {
      strncpy(caETF,caText,8);
      passtofun(caETF); 
      // passtofun() is the logic/function i want to perform on 8 char independently.
   } 
}
```

on the first time it should be take caETF="HELLOGOO" and should pass it to passtofun(caETF).
on the second  it should be take caETF="DMORNING" and should pass it to passtofun(caETF) and likewise till the end of string.
I have tried as above but it works for only first 8 character.How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go!

`strncpy(caETF,caText,8);` modify this as `strncpy(caETF,caText+i,8);` this will work for any case.

String declaration should be like `char *Text = "HELLOGOODMORNING";` not `char caText = "HELLOGOODMORNING";`

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
{
  char *text = "HELLOGOODMORNING"; /* string length 16, array size 17 */

  /* size of these has to accomodate the terminating null */
  char one[8];
  char two[8];


  /* copy 8 characters, starting at index 0 */
  strncpy(two, &text[0], 8);



  /* we can do strcpy if we're at the end of the string.  It will stop when it hits '\0' */
  strcpy(one, &text[7]);

  /* note that we still have to null-terminate the strings when we use strncpy */
  two[2] = '\0';


  /* but we don't have to null-terminate when we use strcpy */
  /* so we can comment this out: one[5] = '\0'; */

  printf("%s\n", one);
  printf("%s\n", two);


  return 0; /* returns 0, since no errors occurred */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the thing your doing actually cannot work because the variable caText you declared is not even a string but a char.
I based the bellow code on the fact that you're just interested in cutting in half the string but you can actually modify the if by any other value

```
 #include <string.h>

    void main()
    {
     char caETF[8 + 1]; // +1 for '\0'
     char caText[]="HELLOGOODMORNING";// here you forget the [] 
     int i,j,len;
     i = 0;
     j = 1; //initialize j = 1 because i devide len by j and you cant divide by 0
     len = strlen(caText) + 1; //add 1 because j = 1
     for (j ; j < len ; j++)
      {
          if (len / j >= 2){  //if middle of string then copy in tmp string
          caETF[i] = caText[j];
          i++;
          }
       }
      caETF[i] = '\0'; //add '\0' so the computer understand that the string is terminated
      passtofun(caETF);  //now you can do whatever you want with that string
    }
```

`caETF[i] = caText[j];` allows you to copy a character from a position `j` to a position `i` in the new array. (eg:`caETF[0] = caText[9]`).